# Name, id, aria, role attributes within HTML

Tags: html, validation, attributes, accessibility

I know that name and id have a key importance when including them in to the web form elements, all these attributes like name, id, role, aria-xxx, title, should always be included inside the html elements?

So, every article, every section, every navigation menu item must have ALL these attributes? Or some of them will be relevant for certain elements, like "name" for webforms or "id" for javascript targeting? Unfortunately, the browser doesn't return me a validation message if some attributes are not supported or not needed. Orientation, please.

In a form is it ok to have it?

`<label for=”first-name”>First Name</label>
<input type=”text” id=”first-name” name=”first-name” required aria-required=”true” role="textbox" aria-labelledBy="something">`

As you see I put required AND aria-required and also a role, might be a conflict? I know that role attribute=textbox is nojt the correct one but just to illustrate my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good question. The TLDR is no, you do not have to add all these attributes for all HTML elements. For more detailed explanation, check the following text.

Each of the attributes you mentioned plays a separate role. Let's take the ones you mentioned as an example:

- id: Used to give an element a unique identifier. Useful to reference using JavaScript `getElementById` and also useful for referencing using other attributes in the same page (like how the `<label for="first-name">` references the input element by id).
- name: This is primarily used to read data of form elements. At some point in time where forms were posted through traditional POST calls to the server, the `name` attribute would denote the keys of the key/value pairs that the server would receive from the web page. Nowadays, people rely on Web API calls and AJAX calls, but they're still used nonetheless.
- role: This is useful for screen readers and assistive. You should put role on HTML elements when their original tag element *does not portray their real semantic in the page*. A common example is people using `div` elements to build tables. In that case, you need to add roles of table, grid, row, cell, etc. for the respective div elements that constitute the table. Had you used the native HTML elements that build tables (, , , etc.), roles would have been redundant.
- aria-xxxx: Also used for screen readers and assistive technologies. There are many types  of aria attributes used for multiple reasons. There is no lack of references out there on the web; you can easily search for them on MDN or other websites. What I want to note here that some attributes render them redundant.

  - Let's take your snippet above as an example. `<input required aria-required="true" />`. The required attribute was introduced in HTML 5 and is enough for screen readers. So if you are targeting modern browsers (which is highly likely), adding `aria-required` is redundant. However if you are targeting browsers that do not support HTML 5, then having it is useful since those browsers would ignore the `required` attribute.
  - Another example taken from you snippet to showcase the same point is that the `aria-labelledBy` is redundant here as well. That is because you already have the input labeled by the `<label>` element by virtue of the `for` attribute. In short, aria attributes are useful if native HTML elements and attributes are not already sufficient.

In summary, each attribute has its different purpose. Not all of them need to be present all the time, it is dependent on your code structure, the HTML elements you are using, the browsers you are targeting, etc.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, helpful and specific. It makes me think that "name" attribute has nothing to do inside an article element for example, because an article is meant to be plain text to read, no interaction involved, unless the scrolling bar, but no buttons, no input field to fill up. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The name attribute makes no sense on an article element

Comment: Excellent answer @OmarSourour! I would add that there might be a good reason why an article might need some kind of name, but that's simply not the same reason why the HTML name **attribute** exists. If you just need a heading for your article, use a standard heading element at an appropriate level. If you need custom metadata in HTML (a completely valid use case), look into data attributes. They let you tag an element with 'almost anything'.

Comment: Great, @Omar Souror. After some time I am reviewing the reply and I'd like to quote something: _“... if you are targeting modern browsers (which is highly likely), adding aria-required is redundant.”_

But does it mean that it can generate a conflict because of this redundant attribute? Modern browser can get confussed? Mi intention is to use it "just in case" to target also old installed browsers (if any exists), what do you think?

Comment: Hey @limakid .. yeah redundant just means that they are unnecessary; the code would work without them. It doesn't mean it would break. If you are targeting old browsers (which I recommend you check if you really have to) then it would be necessary to add aria-required.